# How to filter an array of objects by filtering an array inside of it in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm trying to make an advanced searching for my app, it has a stores array of objects, every store is an object and every store has an array of objects that holds the items of that store, (every item is an object). (i'll leave the stores array down so u understand what i mean)

So basically, I want the user to filter the stores by the item names, but i got stuck and whatever i tried didn't seem to be working.
here is the code:

stores array:

```
let stores = [
  {
    name:"",
    type:"",
    items:[
      {name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"},  //this is what i want to filter with
      {name:"other items here", quantity:"45", unit:"kg"},
      {name:"example item", quantity:"74", unit:"l"},
    ]
  }
]
```

The filtering way I've tried:

```
let userInput = "tomato";


//this outputs the original array without any filtering

    let filteredStores = stores.filter(store=>{
      return store.items.filter(item=>{
        return item.name.includes(userInput)
      })
    })
```

Hope someone understands how i want to filter the stores, thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: In that case with the userInput of "tomato", the output should be `[{name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"}]`

Comment: And there are multiple objects into the ```store``` array?

Comment: @SajeebAhamed yes

Comment: What if the store look like this- ```let stores = [
  {
    name:"",
    type:"",
    items:[
      {name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"}, 
      {name:"other items here", quantity:"45", unit:"kg"},
      {name:"example item", quantity:"74", unit:"l"},
    ]
  },
 {
    name:"",
    type:"",
    items:[
      {name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"},
    ]
  }
];```

Comment: yes it looks like that, stores can have common items, so when the user filters them with "tomato" for example , he gets those 2 stores only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
let stores = [
  {
    name:"",
    type:"",
    items:[
      {name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"},  //this is what i want to filter with
      {name:"other items here", quantity:"45", unit:"kg"},
      {name:"example item", quantity:"74", unit:"l"},
    ]
  },
 {
    name:"",
    type:"",
    items:[
      {name:"tomatos", quantity:"14", unit:"kg"},
    ]
  }
];

let UserInput = "tomato";

const res = stores.filter(({items}) => items.find(item => item.name.includes(UserInput)));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: in ur code, im getting only the items as a result, i want to get the whole store that has those items, hope u understand

Comment: In your comment you said the output would be ```[{name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"}]```

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think this is what you are wanting.

Comment: oh that was a mistake, im sorry, the output would be the whole store that has the items that the user searches for , excuse me plz was a mistake

Comment: well now the stores only have the 1 item,
i want to filter the stores with their items and return the filtered stores without any changes

Comment: check the accepted answer, someone has solved it for me, thanks for trying dude

Answer (score 2):

`Array#filter` will return an empty array when no matches are found. This is a truthy value, you can find this by doing `!!array.filter(() => false)`. You need to call `.length` on the second filter to be able to determine whether it has found any matches or not, `0` is falsey and anything else is truthy.

Comment: you mean smth like this ?
`return store.items.filter(item=>{
        return item.name.includes("d").length
      })`

well that gave me the same input, can u help plz

Comment: @SalahEddineMakdour - that is right. if you wanted to be more explicit you could add `.length > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let stores = [
  {
    name:"",
    type:"",
    items:[
      {name:"tomato", quantity:"145", unit:"g"},  //this is what i want to filter with
      {name:"other items here", quantity:"45", unit:"kg"},
      {name:"example item", quantity:"74", unit:"l"},
    ]
  }
]

let filterdStores = stores.filter(s=>s.items.some(i=>i.name==='tomato'));

console.log(JSON.stringify(filterdStores,null,2));
```

Use efficient `Array.some`

Comment: @SalahEddineMakdour ```Array.some``` will break the internal block when find a match, So it won't search whole of array when saw the match. It is more performant.

Comment: the problem with this that when the page loads, it won't show the stores until i type smth in search bar, so when filter string is empty , it gives an empty array which i don't want

Comment: @SalahEddineMakdour Your fetch function must be flexible and conditional!